# I want to know more about getcontact

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First of all, I apologize for not being good at English.

A function is being implemented to distinguish right and left when a player crashes into a wall.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Wall")
    {
        //rigid.gravityScale = 0;

        Vector2 direction = collision.GetContact(0).normal;

        if (direction.x >= 0)
        {
            Debug.LogError("right");
        }

        if (direction.x <= 0)
        {
             Debug.LogError("left");
        }
    }
}
```

However, if you run it in the above state, unlike what I thought, when the player hits the wall on the right, the left is output, and when the player collides with the wall on the left, the right is output.

Is there a direction.x is based on the wall, not the player, so if you hit the right wall of the player, it is judged that you hit the left wall, so if you hit the left wall, the player hits the right side of the wall standard, so does right output?

Comment: do you know what a normal is? imagine an arrow pointing away from a surface. if you move left and hit a wall, the contact normal will point to the right. You should just flip your "left" and "right" logs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was thinking the same thing, but I wasn't sure, so I was looking for that content.

Comment: The documentation might help you.  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ContactPoint2D.html

Comment: The documentation says: `normal vector, that is the vector that is perpendicular to the surface` which is sufficient explanation imo